# Auto disable secure boot when switching to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, secure-boot, windows-11

Currently, my laptop is set up with dual-boot for Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. However, when using a external adapters in Ubuntu, I need to disable Secure Boot.

Unfortunately, I don't want to disable it when switching to Windows.

I'm wondering if there are any ways or tricks to automatically disable and enable Secure Boot when switching between 2 operating systems?

Comment: No, that defeats the point of secure boot. What you want to do is use the machine owner key (MOK) to sign the Ubuntu kernel, so that Ubuntu boots successfully with secure boot enable

Comment: Can you give more details about what adapter you are using? There may be a solution without disabling secure-boot if you can give the adapter details.